# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to enter a value into specific index of a list?

Tags: c#, list

```
//Script 1 
  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Hat")
        {                    
            sendPickValues.Invoke(0, 1);
        }
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Boot")
            {                    
                sendPickValues.Invoke(4, 1);
            }

//Script 2
 private void OnEnable()
    {
                WearableCollider.sendPickValues += GetPickValues;
    }

    List<int> getVal = new List<int>();
    public void GetPickValues(int selection, int toadd)
        {        
            getVal.Insert(selection,toadd);       
        }
```

I think the first value is entered after calling GetPickValues second time getting error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Insertion index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size.
Parameter name: index"

Aim is to store by taking specific index and storing values inside it.I may take getVal[0] and save -1 and next I need to take getVal[5]=1.
Insert function is used to insert at a specific position right?

Comment: how do you invoke `GetPickValues`? maybe you pass to it index that doesn't exist

Comment: The indexes must be an increment of 0, you can't insert 0 followed by 2. Make sure you start at 0 and increment by one with each insert.

Comment: I want to store 1 and -1 depending on the objects a user chooses.if he chooses first object it should save in 0th index.Similarily user can pick  5th object it should be saved in the 4th index.

Comment: @OmriAttiya tried with arraylist by specifying size....still same issue.Looks like need to use dictionary

Comment: @zyonneo please actually show the code (how you invoke the function) that throw the error

Comment: @OmriAttiya Updated Code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first run your code, you initialize a new (empty) List :

```
List<int> getVal = new List<int>();
```

Since the list have 0 items in it, you cant insert a value at index that does not exists. If you want to simple add items to the list use [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `Insert()`, without an index.

```
getVal.Add(toadd);
```

If you don't want it to be added like this and you want to put something at a specific index, I suggest you to use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes Omri...used a dictionary to solve this issue.